# How to play mp3 file several times in C# form Application?

Tags: c#, forms, for-loop, mp3, openfiledialog

I am new to programming and I created a Simple mp3 player. There is a textbox **txtCount** and when enter 4 in that text box need to play mp3 4 times..

Here my code It always play one time and for loop does not work also.

If I entered 4 in the textbox when mp3 file play at fist time it shows as **3 times playd** and **1 more times need to play** this also wrong and I cannot find the error of code. please help me to solve the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mp3Player
{
    class MusicPlayer
    {
        [DllImport("Winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

        public void open(string file)
        {
            string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        }

        public void play()
        {
            string command = "play MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            string command = "stop MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);

            command = "close MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the comments for the error

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace mp3Player
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            int count, times = 0;
            MusicPlayer player = new MusicPlayer();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void txtOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                txtCount.Enabled = true;
            }

            private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                label1.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
                player.open(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }

            private void txtPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {          
                if (txtCount.Text != "")
                {
                    count = Int32.Parse(txtCount.Text);
                    txtCount.Enabled = false;


    // This is does not work

                    for (times = 0; times < count; times++)
                    {
                        player.play();
                        times++;                    
                        lblCompleted.Text = times + " times Played";
                        lblPending.Text = (count - times) + " times need to play";

                    }


                }
                else {

                    txtCount.Focus();
                }

            }

            private void txtStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                player.stop();
            }



        }

}
```

Comment: Hi.. I did debug the code and what I found is while mp3 is playing code goes though for loop. it does not wait to change label until mp3 finish playing ... Please help me to solve that

Comment: That is another kind of question and not the same as what you just asked, so you will need to ask another question for an answer to that. But before you ask another question, read up on Threading in C#

Answer (score 0):

Remove `times++` from inside the loop.

```
for (times = 0; times < count; times++)
                {
                    player.play();
                    //times++;  //remove this line  
                    //At the end of loop 
                    //lblCompleted.Text = 3
                    //lblPending.Text = 1
                    lblCompleted.Text = times + " times Played";
                    lblPending.Text = (count - times) + " times need to play";

                }
```

`lblCompleted.Text` and `lblPending.Text` shows the latest updated value.

**Edit:**
you can use the [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for to play the music and in that time GUI will wait to update until the music end.

Comment: Hi.. I did debug the code and what I found is while mp3 is playing code goes though for loop. it does not wait to change label until mp3 finish playing ... Please help me to solve that

Answer (score 0):

the for loop starts with 0 but the times variable is increased by 1 after playing but before updating the labels. 
(you don't need to increase the variable times++ within a for loop (except you want it)

I think you should change your code to something like that:

```
for (times = 1; times <= count; times++)
            {
                player.play();                 
                lblCompleted.Text = times + " times Played";
                lblPending.Text = (count - times) + " times need to play";

            }
```

Comment: Hi.. I did debug the code and what I found is while mp3 is playing code goes though for loop. it does not wait to change label until mp3 finish playing ... Please help me to solve that

Comment: vikky suggested to use the background worker that should solve your problem (playing is done in background..)